# php add counter with thousands separator

Tags: php, counter, pageviews

I've tried using the 'number_format' in the code below but did't return the intended result. This counter works, all I want to do is simply show a dot or comma after the thousands change. So instead of 1000 that shows now, to show 1.000.

There's also a related txt file in the same folder where the count data is stored-just saying.

```
<?php 

$fp = fopen("counters/counterlog.txt", "r"); 

$count = fread($fp, 1024); 

fclose($fp); 

$count = $count + 1; 

echo "<p>Pageview: " . $count . "</p>"; 

$fp = fopen("counters/counterlog.txt", "w"); 

fwrite($fp, $count); 

fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Comment: The PHP documentation is for everybody, starter or advanced developers. You just need to have the patience to read it.

Comment: When you start your question with "My question has pretty much been asked before", you can expect a flurry of downvotes and an eventual closing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using number\_format to add thousand separator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459998/using-number-format-to-add-thousand-separator)

Comment: PHP probably has one of the best documentation out there. Anyone, and I mean *anyone*, can easily "follow" it.

Comment: nice attitude bro....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preety straight forward answer for you...

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("counters/counterlog.txt", "r"); 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 
fclose($fp); 
$count = $count + 1; 
echo "<p>Pageview: " . number_format($count) . "</p>"; // <===
$fp = fopen("counters/counterlog.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($fp, $count); 
fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bhavik, this work great! I really appreciate your time and accept my apologies if this appeared as lack of effort to sort it out on my own. I really did a thorough search, just couldn't make it work with this particular syntax.

Answer (score 1):

in short
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

in long:

```
echo "<p>Pageview: " . number_format($count) . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
echo "<p>Pageview: " . number_format($count,3,'.') . "</p>";
```